# Change email content when email is in actived jounery

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, content-builder, email-studio

I've the journey which is actived wherein email send activity is used. Now if I want to change the content of email then is it possible ?
?

Or is there any other best way to design the email Content?, So that if it's used in the email which is in the actived journey and if we change the email content then it'll also reflect in the jounery builder email.

Like Content builder have a Dynamic content but will that fullfil same requirement?

Comment: Is your case probably that you already use the email in another context and now also want to use it in journey builder with some content differences?

Answer (score 5):

Using content builder or editing the e-mail node within the journey, you can update content (even when the journey is active). Anyone new entering the journey or who hasn't received that e-mail yet will get the new e-mail content (just tested this).
You can also create a new version with the newer content and activate that. Those already in the journey will continue to finish the older version, but new members will enter the new version.

Comment: Thank you for your response, which content you've used like have you used Dynamic content to reflect the changes?

Comment: Hey Rushikesh, I've changed dynamic and static content. If you change dynamic content, be aware that the dynamic content would need to be stored in the data extension if it is contact data and may require a new version to edit the entry source to include that date (especially if it is coming from the  Sales or Service Cloud). Some updates have also included hyperlink changes. If you are looking to change an engagement split based on a hyperlink change, I would suggest creating a new version and activating that without stopping the other one.